# Symfony 2 & htaccess: Cannot access CSS from app_dev.php

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I have a symlink from `/var/www/web/` to `/projects/Symfony/web/`. When trying to access my site with `app_dev.php` (ie. `http://localhost/web/app_dev.php`), CSS is linked wrongly (`...web/app_dev.php/css/styles.css`). BUt when accessing `app.php` (non development mode), its OK. So how can I fix this?

htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Gerben, what u mean by hardlink? isit `ln` without `-s`? What difference does that make? I think I should use `RewriteBase /web/`? That seems to work, but I'm not sure how it works :)

Comment: how do you include your css files?

Comment: @kuba, just a simple `<link href="css/styles.css"`. Idealy I should have something like `[web root]/css/styles.css`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to include your stylesheets using asset() twig function:

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/styles.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

It should take care of creating proper links.

If you use PHP templates try:

```
<link href="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('css/styles.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Read more about assets in [Including Stylesheets and Javascripts in Twig](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig) and about PHP templates in [How to use PHP instead of Twig for Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/PHP.html#using-assets-images-javascripts-and-stylesheets).

Comment: If I use PHP, is there a similar method?